# Bash Directory Listing Problems

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I'll keep it short.

This works:

```
List=(/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces/*)
echo $List
```

This does not:

```
List="/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces/*"
List=($List)
echo $List
```

Nor does this:

```
List='/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces/*'
List=($List)
echo $List
```

Don't say to just move the string inside the brackets, this is an example. In my script the string is being generated programmatically. Please explain why variables mess stuff up, and how I can fix it.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: `r\ W` Why does the program generate slashes? What are the quoting rules? Why doesn't it generate just the glob expression, why escaped? Which characters will be escaped?

Comment: It is an example. My program does not generate slashes. When you enter something on the command line with spaces you use backslashes to escape it, and it works the same in a script. PS: Tried to newline, the point I'm trying to make is that it doesn't seem to work when the path is in a variable.

Comment: `List='/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces/*'` Has the slashes. See `echo "$List"` `When you enter something on the command line with spaces you use backslashes to escape it,` There are `'` and `"` and unquoted strings. It depends on the context.

Comment: That echo just returns "/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces/*"

Comment: Yup - _with slashes_.

Comment: Even without slashes it returns the same thing.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the objective is ... keep the backslashes, remove the backslashes, prevent word splitting, something else?  couple issues: `List=($List)` will allow word splitting (ie, `List` will be an array with 3 entries) while `List=("$List")` will disable word splitting (ie, `List` will be an array with 1 entry); `echo $List` (the array) is the same as `echo ${List[0]` (ie, will only display the 0th array entry), consider `typeset -p List` to display entire array

Comment: also, using the same name (`List`) for both scalar and array variables, while technically doable, could lead to confusion for anyone else coming across this code in the future, especially if the assignments and references are sprinkled throughout the main program; case in point is the `echo $List` when `List` is an array ... someone not paying attention may think this is scalar variable reference when if fact it's referencing the 0th element of an array

Answer (score 0):

I would first remove the slashes before spaces first (why are they there?). Then you can use compgen to generate completions from a glob expression. However, compgen output is separated by newlines, so if there is a newline in the filename, the output will be wrong. If your paths have no newlines, this looks like the best option.

```
list=${list//\\ / }
readarray -t array < <(compgen -G "$list")
```

*If the string is escaped for shell and has slashes*, you could use eval. However, this is a security hole and the generated string may then remove all your files, eval is evil.

```
eval "list=($list)"
```

However, I would much prefer that the generated glob is just the glob expression as-is, without escaped space (why?), and then you could use python.

```
list='/home/MyUserName/Desktop/Folder With Spaces/*'
readarray -t -d '' array < <(python -c 'import glob,sys; [print(x,end="\0") for x in glob.glob(sys.argv[1])]' "$list")
```

Also note that `echo $List` is unquoted, so it's only first element of the array and the result undergoes word splitting expansion and filename expansion. Use shellcheck to catch such errors.

Comment: With the given solutions there, `eval` is the only one adaptable to filenames with glob characters.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. All 3 should work with that. `touch 'a*' 'b*' 'ab*'; list='./a*'; readarray -t array < <(compgen -G "$list"); declare -p array` outputs `declare -a array=([0]="./a*" [1]="./ab*")` works fine.

Comment: How do you expand `List='Folder\ with\  spaces\  and\ globs\*/*'`?  Perhaps a cd-first solution will do, unless the `*` in the last filename part is just an example.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE] counterexample.

Comment: I'm mistaken. The compgen solution also works because only the whitespaces are unquoted. Didn't think of it. But the python solution still won't: `mkdir -p "a b c d/f o o __invalid__" "a b c */f o o *" "a b c */f o o __invalid__"; list="a b c */f * \*"; readarray -t -d '' array < <(python -c 'import glob,sys; [print(x,end="\0") for x in glob.glob(sys.argv[1])]' "$list"); declare -p array; list=${list//\\ / }; readarray -t array < <(compgen -G "$list"); declare -p array`

Comment: This is a better example: `mkdir -p "a b c d/f o o __invalid__ *" "a b c */f o o *" "a b c */f o o __invalid__"; list="a b c */f * \*"; readarray -t -d '' array < <(python -c 'import glob,sys; [print(x,end="\0") for x in glob.glob(sys.argv[1])]' "$list"); declare -p array; list="a\ b\ c \*/f\ *\ \*"; list=${list//\\ / }; readarray -t array < <(compgen -G "$list"); declare -p array`. However what I found out is that python's glob solution simply doesn't interpret backslash quoted globs, or maybe it doesn't interpret backslashes at all. So the solution would be to use `[]` instead like `[*]`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this so that I can mark it as an answer, the comment was removed but credits to whoever posted it.

You have to make sure the asterisk is outside of the quotes. For example:
'`/home/MyUserName/Desktop/'*` instead of `'/home/MyUserName/Desktop/*'`.

Comment: Simply put, backslash and quotes are not specially evaluated after parameter expansion.

Comment: This isn't enough though since word splitting will occur.

Comment: You'll also have a problem with glob characters in filenames which you don't want to expand. This includes `[...]` besides `*` and `?`.